# Adjective negation: difference between 〜くない and 〜くありません

Tags: politeness, adjectives, negation, i-adjectives

What's the difference between 〜くない and 〜くありません? Both are added to an i-adjective (イ形容詞, verb type adjective) to make it negative. For example:

- 寒くない
- 寒くありません

But what's the difference? Is one more polite or more formal than the other?

Is there a term to use to tell them apart. E.g. One is polite Negative etc.

Comment: What is a "verb-type-adjective"?

Comment: Same with じゃない vs. ではありません。If you want to use the former in a more formal situation, just say 寒くないです。

Comment: @kiss-o-matic Is there a term to use to tell them apart. E.g. One is polite Negative etc.

Comment: @l'électeur As I understand it, words that end in い are verb-type-adjectives. (I think)

Comment: @l'électeur some people use terminology "adjectival verbs"/"adjectival nouns" vs. "い-adjectives"/"な-adjectives". I've seen that distinction a lot in lessons on basic grammar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- 〜くない (casual)
- 〜くありません (formal)

It's basically that simple. So saying 寒くありません is more formal than saying 寒くない.

However, I feel that saying 寒くありません is a bit stiff even if you are trying to be polite. Instead, saying 寒くないです sounds more natural and is also more polite than leaving off the です.