# What's the meaning of the く in 赤くありません?

Tags: adverbs, i-adjectives

The way of turning 赤 into an adjective is adding い, but what does it mean when instead of a い you put a く？

I found it in this phrase:

> 私のリンゴは赤くありません。

I get the meaning but not the meaning of く.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23772/9749

Comment: Yeah, but why do I have to use く? what does it means? when sould I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that Japanese "adjectives" function differently from English adjectives. You are in this case asking us about a い-adjective, 赤い. Those adjectives differ from the な-adjectives, for example 有名｛ゆうめい｝な:

- The い or な is attached to those adjectives when used as epithets, i.e. they are attached to a noun:

  > 有名な人、赤いリンゴ.
- な-adjectives are used with the copula, dropping the な:

  > この人は有名(です・でした・ではありません)
- い-adjectives are "conjugated", you can use them without modifying the copula (sometimes even remove it entirely)! In your example

  > このリンゴは赤い(です)。

  If you to turn this sentence into a negative one, you modify the adjective, by appending ～くない, i.e. `このリンゴは赤くない(です)`. See for example [this page](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/adjectives) or [this one](http://kimallen.sheepdogdesign.net/Japanese/adjectives.html).

  > このリンゴは赤いではありません。

  is **not** a correct sentence.

Then, as mentioned in the related answer ～くありません is the polite form of ～くない. Thus, it is the polite negative form of the adjective.

Comment: です isn't really a copula in 赤いです, it's a politeness marker:  ① it doesn't inflect, the adjective does, ② the adjective is complete without it, ③ there is no \*赤いだ.  So in short, it doesn't do what a copula does, but it does mark the adjective as polite.